# Pseudorandom correlation generators for many small tensor products

Tags: multiparty-computation, pcg

Pseudorandom correlation generators (PCG) exist for tensor products, this is described in Figure 1 of [1]. Basically we want party 1 to hold $(x_0, z_0)$ and party 2 to hold $(x_1, z_1)$ such that $x_0 \otimes x_1 = z_0 + z_1$. Let $n = |x_0| = |x_1|$ so the length of $z_0, z_1$ is $n^2$.

My understanding is that PCG such as this is only useful for generating a huge amount of correlation. Suppose I want to generate many small tensor product correlations, e.g., $n = 10$. Is there a better way than repeating the tensor product correlation protocol many times for small vectors? The only other option I see for the moment is to do a big tensor product correlation and then take square matrices along the diagonal of size $n \times n$, but this is quite wasteful since majority of the output is not used especially if $n$ is small.

Ideally the communication cost of generating such a correlation is lower then $O(n^2)$ where $n$ is the length of the vector. Otherwise it's possible to just generate multiplication triples.

[1] https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/1035.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a confusion: Figure 1 is about generating batch-OLE correlations (where the product is point-wise, so the $z$ vectors are of length $n$), not tensor products correlations. Its computational cost is $\tilde{O}(n)$ (so, of the order of $n\log n$).

If you want to generate $n$ tensor products of length $k$ each, it can be done with computational cost $k^2 \cdot \tilde{O}(n)$, which is much smaller than $O(n^2)$ for small values of $k$.

The PCG from [1](https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/1035.pdf) handles batch-OLEs: correlations where Alice gets pseudorandom length-$n$ vectors $(x_0, z_0)$ and Bob gets pseudorandom length-$n$ vectors $(x_1, z_1)$ such that $x_0 \odot x_1 = z_0+z_1$ (say, over some prime order field $\mathbb{Z}_p$). Here, I use $\odot$ to indicate the component-wise product of the vectors.

Furthermore, an important feature of these PCG is *programmability*: basically, it is possible to generate other batch-OLE correlations, and in each of them, "fix one of $x_0,x_1$" to remain identical. So, for example, Alice and Bob can get another correlation $(x_0, z'_0)$ and $(x'_1, z'_1)$ such that $x_0 \odot x'_1 = z'_0+z'_1$.

Using this programmability, it is not too hard to get tensor products: you simply want to first generate $k$ batch-OLE, and then use programmability to generate batch-OLE correlations for each of the cross products between the $x_0$'s and the $x_1$'s. This will require $k^2$ such batch-OLE. The seed size therefore grows as $O(k^2 \log n)$ (with some $\mathsf{poly}(\lambda)$ term as well), and the computational cost is $k^2\cdot \tilde{O}(n)$.

Hope that helped, if you don't see how to make it work from there, don't hesitate to ask for further clarification and I'll add details.

Comment: Thank you Geoffroy. There's a detail I'm still missing. The batch-OLE PCG is programmable, but the programmable PCG definition requires Gen to take two additional arguments $\rho_0, \rho_1$. How does the batch-OLE PCG from Figure 1 use those arguments? Are those seeds that samples random vectors for the SPFSS?

Comment: $\rho_0, \rho_1$ would be the random values sampled in step 1 of Gen, than is, $\rho_\sigma = (A^i_\sigma, \vec b^i_\sigma)_{i \leq c}$. They can indeed be replaced by short seeds that are fed to a PRG to generate these values pseudorandomly.

Comment: It seems for batching to work one needs to work over $R_t = Z_t/F(X)$ so that it's isomorphic to $Z_t/F_1(X) \times \dots \times Z_t/F_r(X)$. This seems to be challenging if I want each of $Z_t/F_i(X)$ to be binary, i.e., computing binary OLE/outer product correlation. Is there a workaround or this is the limitation?

Comment: This is a great question! Indeed, the approach based on ring-LPN only gives you a batch of $n$ OLEs over $\mathbb{Z}_t$ when $t > n$, and this is the main limitation of this construction. If you want to construct it over, say, $\mathbb{F}_2$, then any silent OT protocol works (e.g. [this one](ia.cr/2019/448)), because an OT is equivalent to an OLE over $\mathbb{F}_2$. However, there are two strong downsides: (1) this *only* works over $\mathbb{F}_2$ (not $\mathbb{F}_3$ or any larger ring) and (2) the resulting batch OLE is not programmable anymore!

Comment: The natural question is therefore: is there a way to overcome this limitation over arbitrary small rings, and without loosing the programmability features? And of course, we want it with cost much less than $n^2$ (with cost $n^2$, the construction on section 10 [here](ia.cr/2022/1035) works). This is a hard problem, but there are some results: for example, we have such a construction from a new LPN variant in this [recent paper](ia.cr/2022/1014): see section 5.3. But it's still quite costly!

Comment: I'm a bit confused with your comment on the construction on section 10 of ia.cr/2022/1035 (specifically Figure 14). I can see how it can give a large tensor product correlation. But I don't immediately see how it gives many small tensor product correlations. Or is this not possible? Additionally, what do you mean by cost $n^2$, is this the computation cost which seems to be dominated by doing matrix multiplication?

Comment: One big size-$n$ tensor product correlation *contains* in particular all the sub-tensor correlations. So if you want $n$ pairs of length-$k$ vectors, you can generate one big tensor correlation between length-$n\cdot k$ vector, and it will contain in particular the $n$ $k\times k$ tensors (and much more: all the cross tensors). The cost will be $\Omega(k^2n^2)$ (at least -- can be even more, e.g. if you use LPN with unstructured matrices), which is why I describe a much more efficient method with cost $O(k^2 n)$ in my answer. Cost refers to the computation for each party.